# Problema na playstore

Tags: android

Estou com problemas para atualizar meu app na google playstore, ele aponta erro no formulario de "detalhes do produto" mas eu nao mechi em nada la, esta como sempre esteve publicado. mas sempre aparece "Verifique erros nos idiomas especificados acima."

mas nunca alterei nada, e ta dando esse erro porque?

Answer (score 2):

Isso é muito provável que seja devido as mudanças recentes do Google play, nos **Detalhes do app** eles incluíram um novo campo chamado "Breve descrição" e existe uma nova imagem obrigatória que se chama "Gráfico de recursos", eles passaram a ser obrigatórias faz pouco tempo e não se pode publicar nenhuma versão nova enquanto não preencher eles.